# How to watch samba shared folder/drive using filesystemwatcher in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, shared, filesystemwatcher

Here is some tricky problem.
I am trying to watch a shared folder which is on Linux machine.
I am running the program on windows XP which is developed in Visual Studio 2005, VC++
and using FileSystemWatcher class.
But it's not raising events for that shared folder at all.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please post an example of your code, especially the file path.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, instead of a proper solution, is the following: If you have access on the Linux machine you could use inotify to detect file changes and communicate them to your application over the net.